# Calculating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{2^nn(3n-1)}}$

Tags: summation

I'd appreciate any help, I know it has something to do with the geometric series but I still can't figure out how. I thought about integration but couldn't find a way to do it.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^nn(3n-1)}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I used Mathematica to compute a numerical result, and it gave me $S = 0.28232(...)$. The result of the finite series, instead, is expressed in terms of HyperGeometric Functions. At least you have the result. Not let's concentrate on the procedure.

Comment: Try to consider $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n(3n-1)} = 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{3n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ (in your case, $x=1/2$) and see if you can massage this to have a closed-form expression for $f(x)$ (using results on integration of power series, after a change of indices for the first term). After all is done, plug back the $1/2$ to get $f(1/2)$.

Comment: @ClementC.  Clearly you have not tasted your own medicine :)

Comment: @uniquesolution Which means? (I posted that as a comment exactly because I didn't attempt the full, detailed solution, which is also why I started with "Try to." That is the way I'd attempt to tackle the problem, however...)

Comment: @ClementC Thanks guys, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @uniquesolution Are you sure?  The integral of $y/(1-y^3)$ is straightforward, albeit ugly.

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't see why -- see my answer below. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: @ClementC.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Outline:** Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n(3n-1)}$, for $x \in (-1,1)$. Everything is well-defined and one can rewrite
$$
f(x) = 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{3n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}.
$$
You are looking for $f(\frac12)$. Now, getting a closed-form expression for $h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ is not hard (and has been treated many times on this website), so let's focus on the first term (which is similar, albeit trickier). Setting $t=x^{1/3}$, we actually are interested in
$$
g(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{3n}}{3n-1} = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{3n-1}}{3n-1} = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^t u^{3n-2} du = 
\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty u^{3n-2} \right)du
$$
which can be rewritten as follows (note that all above is "legit" for $t\in(0,1)$, by properties of power series within their radius of convergence):
$$
g(t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \frac{du}{u^2} \frac{u^3}{1-u^3} = 
\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \frac{u}{1-u^3} du
$$
which can be computed by standard means (even though it's not my favourite activity, by far). This gives you a closed-form expression for $g(t)$; hence for $f(x) = 3g(x^{1/3}) - h(x)$. It remains to plug in $x=1/2$ to conclude.

Comment: Yes!  Exactly as in my comment.  Well done.  +1

Comment: This is well done. (+1)

Comment: Nothing wrong here -- my first comment was merely trying to hint that there was some work to be done... thanks for carrying it out.

Answer (score 3):

$$\log\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\log\frac{1}{1-x^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\log\frac{1}{1-x^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{3n-2}}{n}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}\frac{1}{x^2}\log\frac{1}{1-x^3}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}\frac{x^{3n-2}}{n}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}\frac{1}{x^2}\log\frac{1}{1-x^3}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{n2^n(3n-1)}$$
so 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n(3n-1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}\frac{1}{x^2}\log\frac{1}{1-x^3}dx$$
$$=-\log 2+\frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{2}}\log(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}+1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\log(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}})-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt{3}})+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{3}}$$
$$=0.282319554....$$

Comment: Very nice !  (+1)

Comment: @uniquesolution thanks

Answer (score 0):

The approach with hypergeometric functions is
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n(3n-1)} \frac{1}{2^n}
=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)(3n+2)} \frac{1}{2^n}
=
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2/3)} \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
$$
=
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(1)_n(2/3)_n}{(2)_n(2/3)(5/3)_n} \frac{1}{2^n}
=
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(1)_n(2/3)_n(1)_n}{(2)_n(5/3)_n} \frac{1}{2^nn!}
=
\frac{1}{4}{}_3F_2(1,1,2/3;2,5/3;1/2)
$$
By the known contiguous relations, see e.g. Gottschalk and Maslen "Reduction
formulae for generalised hypergeometric functions of one variable" in J. Phys A 21 (1988) 1983-1998:
$$
(1-2/3){}_3F_2(1,1,2/3;2,5/3;1/2)
=
{}_3F_2(1,2,2/3;2,5/3;1/2)
-
(2/3)
{}_3F_2(1,1,5/3;2,5/3;1/2)
$$
$$
=
{}_2F_1(1,2/3;5/3;1/2)
-
(2/3)
{}_2F_1(1,1;2;1/2).
$$

There is a well known (Abramowitz-Stegun 15.1.4)
$$
{}_2F_1(1,1;2;z)= -\frac{1}{z}\log(1-z)
$$
for the second term on the right hand side.

For the first term on the right hand side we have the integral representation (Abramowitz-Stegun)
$$
{}_2F_1(1,2/3;5/3;1/2)
=\frac{\Gamma(5/3)}{\Gamma(2/3)}\int_0^1 t^{-1/3} (1-t/2)^{-1} dt
=\frac23\int_0^1 t^{-1/3} (1-t/2)^{-1} dt
$$
Substituting $t=x^3$, $dt/dx=3x^2$ this
is
$$
=\frac23\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-x^3/2} 3x^2dx
=2\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1-x^3/2} dx
$$
which is known by the Gradsteyn-Gyzhik formula 2.126
$$
\int \frac{x dx}{a+bx^3} = -\frac{1}{3b\alpha}\left[\frac12 \ln\frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x^2-\alpha x +\alpha^2}-\surd 3 \arctan\frac{2x-\alpha}{\surd 3 \alpha}\right]
$$
where $\alpha\equiv \sqrt{3}(a/b)$.